# Why the image can not open?

Tags: python, tkinter

I copied and pasted these codes, but mine is returning errors. I modified the codes several times but the error remains the same.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('TEST')
root.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
root.geometry("1008x720")

bg = PhotoImage(file="image.jpg")

my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=1080, height=720)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

my_canvas.create_image(0, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER-DAF005\PycharmProjects\Background_test\main.py", line 8, in <module>

    bg = PhotoImage(file="image.jpg")

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "image.jpg": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Is `image.jpg` in the same folder as where you are executing the code from? The error says it can't find it.

Comment: Yes, the image is in it. I even tried to move it and copy the path that leads to the image but it always returns the same error.

Comment: To see if it is a location issue, try to use the full absolute path to the file!

Comment: Print `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: how do you run your script?

Comment: Even if you end up fixing all this, jpeg cannot be ready directly by tkinter.

Comment: I have already changed to png but still nothing :(

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is from PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

what command are you using to run the script ?
When you open a file in Python, in general, it looks for the file in the current directory (i.e. whatever you might cd to), rather than using the directory that the script sits in.

so in your program, add this :

```
import os
...
print(os.getcwd())
```

This will make your program print your current directory, and you need to check that the file exists in that directory.

Comment: Still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Python tries to find files in two different ways. via **absolute path** or **relative path**. if you don't specify the full path to the file it considers relative path and the problem with relative path is that **path** to the file should be relative to the path that runs the script. when you use an IDE, you may be inside a different directory.

You can easily use the `join` method of `os.path` to resolve this problem. So whenever you try to run your script, it will find the relative path to the file dynamically and at the runtime.

```
import os
...
bg = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'image.jpg'))
```

Comment: Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.